# Why does Collection.sort order integers strangely?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a method in my system which sorts tables based on what column header the user clicks. The different columns containg different data types, ie col 1 contains string, col 2 contains int etc.

In the sortSearchTable method we have implemented Collections.sort (List list). However, when calling the method for sorting a column o integers I get this result:

Sorted list: [1, 1, 123, 12324, 22, 3, 567, 789, 975, 99, 99]

ofcourse I want the result as:

Sorted list: [1, 1, 3, 22, , 99, 99, 123, 567, 789, 975, 12324]

What am I missing here? I understand the the collections.sort must sort each character in the integer and thereby it is natural that 123 must come before 22 ,for example, but how can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: They are ordered alphabetically, can we get your code?

Comment: You're ordering `Strings` and not `Integers`.

Comment: If you'd provide actual *code* instead of a description, we could probably tell you pretty easily. I strongly suspect that the problem is that you're sorting strings rather than integers, but we can't tell for sure without seeing code.

Comment: Code example of the sortSearchTable() method:

http://pastebin.com/nWKq2TdK

Comment: @svenan *"Code example of the sortSearchTable() method"* please include the code in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your String list to Integer list and sort it.

Make sure your string list contains valid numbers or handle run time  conversion errors.

```
   //Create a new Integet List
   List<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   //Your String list
   List<String> sList = Arrays.asList("1", "567", "1", "99", "123", "22", "12324", "3", "789", "975", "99");

   sList.forEach(s->iList.add(Integer.valueOf(s)));

   Collections.sort(iList);

   System.out.println("Sorted Integer List");
   for (int number : iList) 
   {
       System.out.println(number);
   }
```